# How can I filter foreignkeys in models?

Tags: python, django

I have created two models, Porumbei and Perechi. Porumbei means pigeon and it can be male or female, they live in pairs(Perechi). My models below(part of it)

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    sexul = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sexul


class Porumbei(models.Model):
    ....
    serie_inel = models.CharField(....)
    sex = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ....

class Perechi(models.Model):
    ....
    mascul = models.ForeignKey(Porumbei, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    femela = models.ForeignKey(Porumbei, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

My form:

class AdaugaPereche(forms.Form):
    boxa = forms.IntegerField(label="Boxa", min_value=1)
    sezon = forms.CharField(label="Sezon reproducere", initial=datetime.now().year)
    mascul = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Porumbei.objects.filter(sex__sexul="Mascul", perechi_masculi__isnull=True), label="Mascul")
    femela = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Porumbei.objects.filter(sex__sexul="Femelă", perechi_femele__isnull=True), label="Femela")
    serie_pui_1 = forms.CharField(label="Serie pui 1")
    serie_pui_2 = forms.CharField(label="Serie pui 2")
    culoare_pui_1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CuloriPorumbei.objects.all(), label="Culoare pui 1")
    culoare_pui_2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CuloriPorumbei.objects.all(), label="Culoare pui 2")
    data_imperechere = forms.DateField(label="Dată împerechere")
    primul_ou = forms.DateField(label="Primul ou")
    data_ecloziune = forms.DateField(label="Dată ecloziune")
    data_inelare = forms.DateField(label="Dată inelare")
    comentarii = forms.Textarea()

My view:

def perechenoua(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AdaugaPereche(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("porumbei")
else:
    form = AdaugaPereche()
context = {
    'form': form
}
template = loader.get_template("adauga_pereche.html")
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

The template:

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.boxa|add_class:"form-control" }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.sezon|add_class:"form-control" }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.mascul|add_class:"form-control custom-select d-block w-100" }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.femela|add_class:"form-control custom-select d-block w-100" }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.serie_pui_1|add_class:"form-control" }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form.serie_pui_2|add_class:"form-control custom-select d-block w-100" }}
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.culoare_pui_1|add_class:"form-control custom-select d-block w-100" }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.culoare_pui_2|add_class:"form-control custom-select d-block w-100" }}
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.data_imperechere }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.primul_ou }}
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.data_ecloziune }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.data_inelare }}
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
             {{ form.comentarii }}
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

When I create a new Perechi(pair), the field mascul I want to be sorted with all male in Porumbei(pigeons) and once it has been added to pairs, the next time when adding pairs that male to be excluded from list because it already have pair. The same with female. How can I implement this?

Comment: in Gender model do you have field name ? where male/female is written ?

Comment: and what values are provided in it ?

Comment: I just edited the post with gender class.

Comment: you can't have two foreign keys to the same model without giving them a different `related_name`. But apart from that, in your ModelForm, you have a `ModelChoiceField` to which you can pass a QuerySet. `qs = Porumbei.objects.filter(sex=Gender.objects.get(sexul="male"))` give you all the male pigeons.

Comment: What about gay pairs? ;-)

Comment: It's not productive to have gay pairs when breeding pigeons. :)

Comment: And about showing only male/female that are single in that queryset? Not stored in pairs table?

Comment: why can a pigeon be in multiple pairs, I thought they were pretty monogamous animals? You're sure you don't want a `OneToOneField`? (makes some queries easier if you can do that)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `limit_choices_to` argument of `ForeignKey` to directly limit the choices:

```
from django.db.models import Q

mascul = models.ForeignKey(Porumbei, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   limit_choices_to=Q(sex__sexul="male",
   related_name="pairs_as_male"))
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)'s the documentation.

With the `related_name` you can also query the reverse relationship:

```
Porumbei.objects.filter(sex__sexul="male", pairs_as_male__isnull=True)
```

will give you male pigeons that aren't paired yet.

Comment: Where I must use it? In models or in form definitions ?

Comment: It give me TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Porumbei object when render the page. I edited the post with the form, view and template. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full error trace? Not sure what you’re doing. Your form is just a simple `Form` so you can’t `form.save()` (for that you need a `ModelForm`. But that’s not where the error comes from

Comment: TypeError at /perechi/adauga-pereche/
cannot unpack non-iterable Porumbei object
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/perechi/adauga-pereche/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
cannot unpack non-iterable Porumbei object   I think the problem is on choice field because, redered without these two fields, mascul and femela, the template is render up